# Рендеринг с ошибками. Как поменять версию SDK в gradle по умолчанию?

Tags: android-studio

При создании проекта из шаблона в Android Studio возникают проблемы с рендерингом лэйаута.

Например, в Basic Activity вылезает вот такая ошибка:

> 'Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme'

в Empty Activity вот такая:

> 'Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.'

Соответственно при этом нормальный предпросмотр невозможен.
Пока как решение я нашел следующий способ: в настройках gradle эти строки

> compileSdkVersion 28
>        targetSdkVersion 28
>        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
>        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'

меняю на:

> compileSdkVersion 27
>        targetSdkVersion 27
>        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
>        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

и тогда рендеринг работает, хотя в Basic Activity ошибка остается, но по крайней мере лэйауты я вижу.

В чем может быть причина, что встроенные шаблоны не работают "из коробки" и как решить эту проблему? Или хотя бы как настроить программу, чтобы по умолчанию версия sdk была 27, чтобы в каждом новом проекте не менять настройки вручную?

Comment: это глюк какой то последней сборки студии, наверное исправят со следующим обновлением. Вряд ли вы за это время напишите больше одного проекта :)

Comment: Я только учусь, поэтому могу создавать с десяток новых проектов в день:) Но если так, то подожду.

Comment: все костыли по проблеме [в одном месте](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34499839/7566397)